# Angular: mapping JSON with custom parameter to an object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm new in Angular, so the solution for my question might be quite simple though I'm struggling to find it. The question linked with the JSON mapping to an object through typescript. It's quite obvious how to map simple data types, but in my case I have a JSON object with a string parameter that represent a custom data format. It looks this way:

```
{
            "id": 2,
            "coordinates": "POLYGON ((93.85459125041562 2.2894918584196797, 93.85478973388572 2.2894543170028445, 93.85515987873577 2.2895723043110532, 93.8554173707562 2.2897761005578046))"
        }
```

I was trying to parse it in the constructor but it seems like it don't invokes:

```
    export class RegionModel {
      public _pointsType: string;
  public _points: CoordinateModel[];
  public _centerPoint: CoordinateModel;

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public coordinates: string
  ) {

    const regex = /([^\)\(]+)(?=\))/g;

    if (coordinates != null && coordinates.length > 0) {
      let longSum = 0;
      let latSum = 0;
      const str = regex.exec(coordinates)[0];
      str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(',').forEach((value, index, array) => {
        const longLatString = value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(' ');
        latSum += Number(longLatString[1]);
        longSum += Number(longLatString[0]);
        this._points.push(new CoordinateModel(
          Number(longLatString[1]), Number(longLatString[0]))
        );
      });
      this._centerPoint = new CoordinateModel(
        latSum / this._points.length,
        longSum / this._points.length
      );
    }

get points(): CoordinateModel[] {
    return this._points;
  }

  get pointsType(): string {
    return this._pointsType;
  }

  get centerPoint(): CoordinateModel {
    return this._centerPoint;
  }

  set centerPoint(value: CoordinateModel) {
    this._centerPoint = value;
  }

  set coordinates(value: CoordinateModel[]) {
    this._coordinates = value;
  }
  }

export class CoordinateModel {
      constructor(
        public lat: number,
        public lon: number
      ) {}
    }
```

Can anyone help me to find a good solution to parse this kind of data?

Comment: You'll have to write it yourself, using string manipulation: split, substring, etc. (unless this is a standard format for which libraries exist). Where does this come from?

Comment: it comes from third party API

Comment: Which one? Does it provide a SDK/library to parse these custom strings? If it doesn't, have you tried parsing the string by yourself? What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: It's a geoJSON string. There should be librarys to parse these. Failing that, split the string on `,`, and map the array into your objects

Comment: yes, I know that I need to transform this string parameter. but I need to find a way how to do this better. As example I was trying to do this in the constructor itself, but it seems like it's not invoking.

Comment: Before trying to do this better, you should try to do it, period. What have you tried? Where is the code you tried?

Comment: When you say you were trying to do it in the constructor itself, what do you mean? Can you show us what you tried please? And explain what bit of it didn't work / what the behaviour was

Comment: yes, I have modified the description. please take a look

Comment: I've just seen that. What was not working in that solution? (You may need to initialise `this._points` from the look of it)

Comment: *it seems like it don't invokes*: now where is the code where you invoke that constructor. if you don't have `new RegionModel(...)` anywhere in the code, then yes, this constructor will never be invoked. In particular, Angular doesn't know anything about this class, and will never, ever call its constructor.

Comment: I parse recevied JSON object through map method from rx.observable: this.get(url, httpParams).map((regions: RegionModel[]) => { return regions ? regions : undefined; }) and I expected that it will initialize new models the same way as I initialize it through "new" method. but it seems like it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to use regex to capture the coordinates:

```
const coordinatesArray = coordinates.match(/(\d+\.\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+)/g);
this._points = coordinatesArray.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const latLong = current.split(" ");
  acc.push(
    new CoordinateModel(Number(latLong[0]), Number(latLong[1]))
  );
  return acc;
}, []);
```

If you say that your constructor is not invoked is because you're not using your class as is supposed, which is `new RegionModel(id, coordinates)`.

**NOTE:** Parsing your string in the constructor would be fine, in this way you hide the implementation details from the rest of your logic, if you need to change the way that you parse the string (due to another String representation), you just need to update the `RegionModel` class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes indeed I didnt use it through this initializiotion instead I maped it through map from rx.observable: this.get(url, httpParams).map((regions: RegionModel[]) => {
      return regions ? regions : undefined;
    })

Comment: and it works fine, I receive an array of objects, but why it dont invoke constructor body the same way as when I initialize it through new method?

Comment: without using the `new` keyword, RegionModel just acts like an interface, which enforces the structure of the element, [this article would be helpful](https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks this helped me out.